# Random Favicon On Web Page

Tags: php, html, favicon

I am trying to show a different favicon on each refresh of the browser from a selection of 3 images.  Here is the code which i currently have:

```
<head>
<!--Other Stuff-->
<?
$faviconNumber = rand(1,3);
if ($faviconNumber == 1) {
  echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="../img/favicon1.ico"/>';
}
else if ($faviconNumber == 2) {
  echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../img/favicon2.png"/>';
}
else {
  echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../img/favicon3.png"/>';
}
?>
</head>
```

There are 3 different favicons (2 png, 1 ico).  However when this is run it will only ever show the second favicon.

Comment: favicon1.png are referenced twice!

Comment: It should serve `random` for sure just `echo $faviconNumber;`  to test whether you got `1 or 2 or 3` .

Comment: That was just to change the names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your icon names like favicon_1.ico, favicon_2.ico and favicon_3.

After this, please change your code like below.

```
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="../img/favicon_<?php echo rand(1,3); ?>.ico"/>
</head>
```